# "This workbook cannot be opened..." on 64bit IE

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, office

So,

The message when trying to open an excel file from SharePoint goes like this

[image]

This happens when I use IE, specifically the 64bit version. If I use the 32bit version, it runs fine.

Now, this is ok for me as I can manually open up 32bit when needed, but for our thousands of users, this won't be the case. Is there a simple workaround at all to enable it to work on 64bit versions?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64795/excel-document-opening-in-browser-unsupported-features

Comment: The thing is that it is very sporadic